# Vectors passed to function aren't being modified

Tags: c++, function, vector

So I am making a function to take certatin elements of a vector and storing them into another vector. Whenever I run the program, it gives a segmentation fault error? Why does this happen and how can I fix things so that this doesn't happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void addition (vector <char> a, vector <string> b)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (a[i] == '3')
    {
      b.push_back("3");
    }
    if (a[i] == '4')
    {
      b.push_back("4");
    }
    if (a[i] == '+')
    {
      b.push_back("+");
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector <char> v1 = {'3', '4', '+', '3', '4'};
  vector <string> v2;

  addition(v1, v2);
  cout << v2[0] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why? I am confused

Comment: I didn't look closely enough, my mistake. Took it back

Comment: The flow of the program will become a lot clearer if you avoid using out-parameters. E.g. ```vector<string> addition(vector<char> a)```. There are many other good reasons to avoid them.

Comment: @bastwendo Are you confused as to why `int foo(int x) { x = 10; } int main() { int z = 1; foo(z); }` doesn't make `z` equal to 10 after `foo` is called?  It is for the same reason your vectors are not changing -- it's called *pass by value*.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter `b` is declared as pass-by-value, so it's just a copy of the argument, and any modification on it inside `addition()` has nothing to do with the original argument passed-in (i.e. `v2` in `main()`). Then `cout << v2[0] << endl;` will lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (means anything is possible), because `v2` is still empty.

You should change it to pass-by-reference, e.g.

```
void addition (vector <char> a, vector <string>& b)
//                                             ~
```

BTW: `a` should be declared as pass-by-reference too, to avoid unnecessary copy, .e.g

```
void addition (const vector <char>& a, vector <string>& b)
```

Comment: After 4 years I think I understand my mistake. I didn't understand the difference between pass by value and pass by reference. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

You pass a copy of the vectors and not a reference.
Change:

```
void addition (vector <char> a, vector <string> b)
```

into:

```
void addition (const vector <char> &a, vector <string> &b)
```

Note: I changed `a` to a reference too just to save unnecessary copies, and made it const to make sure it isn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

You have passed a new copy of the vector `v2`. So the changes made to `v2` in the function are actually made to its copy, not `v2`.
As a result `v2` actually remains empty, and accessing `v2[0]` gives segmentation fault.
Solution is to pass reference of `v2` as
  `void addition (vector <char> a, vector <string> &b)`